# Handling Date and time with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a project that involves analyzing WhatsApp log data.
After preprocessing the log file I have a table that looks like this:

```
DD/MM/YY | hh:mm | name | text |
```

I could build a graph where, using a chat with a friend of mine, I plotted a graph of the number of text per month and the mean number of words per month but I have some problems:

- If in a month we didn't exchange text the algorithm doesn't count that month, therefore in the graph I want to see that month with 0 messages
- there is a better way to utilize dates and time in python? Using them as strings isn't so intuitive but online I didn't found anything useful.

[this is the GitLab page of my project.](https://gitlab.com/GiuseppeMinardi/whatsgraph)

```
  def wapp_split(line):

      splitted = line.split(',')
      Data['date'].append(splitted[0])
      splitted = splitted[1].split(' - ')
      Data['time'].append(splitted[0])
      splitted = splitted[1].split(':')
      Data['name'].append(splitted[0])
      Data['msg'].append(splitted[1][0:-1])


   def wapp_parsing(file):
      with open(file) as f:
          data = f.readlines()
          for line in data:
              if (line[17:].find(':')!= -1):
                  if (line[0] in numbers) and (line[1]in numbers):

                      prev = line[0:35]
                      wapp_split(line)
                  else:

                      line = prev + line
                      wapp_split(line)
```

Those are the main function of the script. The WhatsApp log is formatted like so:

```
DD/MM/YY, hh:mm - Name Surname: This is a text sent using WhatsApp
```

The parsing function just take the file and send each line to  the split *function*. Those if in the parsing function just avoid that mssages from WhatsApp and not from the people in the chat being parsed.

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, could you please edit your question adding related code snippets of the script,  your input and the expected and actual output?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question as soon as my class ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the table you have is a .csv file that looks like this (call it msgs.csv):

```
date;time;name;text
22/10/2018;11:30;Maria;Hello how are you
23/10/2018;11:30;Justin;Check this
23/10/2018;11:31;Justin;link
22/11/2018;11:30;Maria;Hello how are you
23/11/2018;11:30;Justin;Check this
23/12/2018;11:31;Justin;link
22/12/2018;11:30;Maria;Hello how are you
23/12/2018;11:30;Justin;Check this
23/01/2019;11:31;Justin;link
23/04/2019;11:30;Justin;Check this
23/07/2019;11:31;Justin;link
```

Now you can use pandas to import this csv in a table format that will recognise both date and time as a timestamp object and then for your calculations you can group the data by month.

```
import pandas as pd
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv('msgs.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']], date_parser=dateparse)

per = df.date_time.dt.to_period("M")
g = df.groupby(per)

for i in g:
    print('#######')
    print('year: {year} ; month: {month} ; number of messages: {n_msgs}'
          .format(year=i[0].year, month=i[0].month, n_msgs=len(i[1])))
```

## EDIT - no information about specific month = 0 messages:

In order to get the 0 for months in which no messages were sent you can do like this (looks better than above too):

```
import pandas as pd
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv('msgs.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']], date_parser=dateparse)

# create date range from oldest message to newest message
dates = pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime([df.date_time.min(), df.date_time.max()]) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()), freq='M')

for i in dates:
    df_aux = df[(df.date_time.dt.month == i.month) & (df.date_time.dt.year == i.year)]

    print('year: {year} ; month: {month} ; number of messages: {n_msgs}'
          .format(year=i.year, month=i.month, n_msgs=len(df_aux)))
```

## EDIT 2: parse logs into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'logs':['DD/MM/YY, hh:mm - Name Surname: This is a text sent using WhatsApp',
                   'DD/MM/YY, hh:mm - Name Surname: This is a text sent using WhatsApp']})

pat = re.compile("(?P<date>.*?), (?P<time>.*?) - (?P<name>.*?): (?P<message>.*)")

df_parsed = df.logs.str.extractall(pat)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to convert the strings into datetime objects

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('22/10/18', '%d/%m/%y')
```

When converting from a string, remember to use the correct seperators, ie "-" or "/" to match the string, and the letters in the format template on the right hand side of the function to parse with the date string too.  Full details on the meaning of the letters can be found at [Python strptime() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for adding missing dates and plotting the mean value of msg_len is to create a date range your interested in then reindex:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1 = df[['msg_len','year']]
df1.index = df1.index.to_period('m')

         msg_len   year
date        
2016-08   11       2016
2016-08    4       2016
2016-08    3       2016
2016-08    4       2016
2016-08   15       2016
2016-10   10       2016

# look for date range between 7/2016 and 11/2016
idx = pd.date_range('7-01-2016','12-01-2016',freq='M').to_period('m')
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby(df1.index)['msg_len'].mean()).reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
new_df.plot()

        msg_len
2016-07   0.0
2016-08   7.4
2016-09   0.0
2016-10   10.0
2016-11   0.0
```

you can change mean to anything if you want the count of messages for a given month etc.